# What are the small windows called in news-style mid shots?

Tags: editing, visual-effects, studio

What is the name of these picture in picture squares that come up on studio mid shots?

I've seem them used on YT as well for similar news-style channels.

There's an industry term and I can't remember what it is...

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an "[over the shoulder](https://www.newscaststudio.com/tv-news-graphics-package/)" graphic. One possible creator of the form was [Ben Blank](https://www.nytimes.com/2009/02/18/arts/television/18blank.html).

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you :)